# Generic wrapper for stored procedure execution

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

How can I execute stored procedures generically?  I tried:

`_context.Set<TEntity>();`

I want to avoid embedded SQL such as:

`context.Database.SqlQuery<TEntity>(storedProcedureName);`

However, because the stored procedure is accessed via a Function rather than a Type this does not work.  I also tried creating/accessing via a function mapping.  The complex type for the return result exists, but this can't be used to obtain the result itself.

Do I need Delegates or is there support for this somewhere?

To be clear, I hope to create something like....

```
public IEnumerable<TEntityResult> ReadSpAll<TEntity,TEntityResult>(IEnumerable<SqlParameter> sqlParameters)
```

where `TEntity` is the stored proc and `TEntityResult` is the complex return type

Answer (score 0):

See "Using Import Functions to Map Stored Procedures"
@ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx

for code like

```
var context = new AWEntities();
ObjectResult<OrderDetail> orderDetailEnumerable = context.GetDetailsForOrder(71796);
List<OrderDetail> details = orderDetailEnumerable.ToList();
```

Comment: This does not use generics.  I need a solution that works generically so I can use it for all stored procs in a repository pattern.

Comment: Sorry mate I dont know a way to call procs like that. I'm guessing you want this signature for a base repository...?
public T CallProcByName<T>(string name, IEnumerable<SqlParameter> params)

Comment: I'm thinking it will look more like:  `public IEnumerable<TEntityResult> ReadSpAll<TEntity,TEntityResult>(IEnumerable<SqlParameter> params)` where `TEntity` is the stored proc and TEntityResult is the complex return type.